# How can I improve the rendering of JLabels?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a quick and dirty swing UI. My UI has a couple of JTextFields, then a JTextArea in a JScrollPane, since the JTextArea's contents may get large.

I am using a simple BoxLayout, I didnt want to waste hours with GridBagLayout.

My problem is, when I resize the window, the JLabels become huge. They will have one single line of text sitting in huge amounts of empty space. It looks ugly and is wasteful. The JTextArea, on the other hand, will never increase in size because JScrollPane takes care of extra content. So I will have huge JTextFields and a tiny JTextArea in a scroll pane with barely one line visible.

Is there an easy way to make sure that the JTextFields never increase their height beyond one line of text ? Maybe overriding getMaximumSize/getPreferredSize ? If so, what would the code be ?

The only function that will resolve this situation is JFrame.pack(), but it will change the window size(highly undesirable) and sometimes doesnt bother confining itself to the desktop.

Comment: "I am trying to create a quick and dirty swing UI"...is there any other type of swing UI? :)

Comment: Well there is that slow, fat, sweaty and still dirty GridBagLayout :).
On a serious note, what UI should I use if I am writing a serious app in Java ?

Comment: Frankly speaking swing has improved a whole lot since 1.4, particularly in 1.5 and 1.6. If you are developing desktop apps, you dont have much options anyway. The other java options you have is SWT and QT. I have not used QT myself, but SWT is pretty ok, but you wont find may SWT developers to maintain your code in a long run.

Answer (score 2):

```
label.setMaximumSize( label.getPreferredSize() );
```

Or better yet, override the getMaximumSize() method to return the preferred size.

Actually, I take that suggestion back since the maximum size of the label is the preferred size. However, that is a technique that will work with other components, like a JTextField for example when using a BoxLayout.

Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Edit:

Actually I think the problem is that BoxLayout tries will increase the height of all the components when there is extra space. To solve this you need to use:

```
panel.add( Box.createVerticalGlue() );
```

as the last component to prevent extra space from being allocated to the components.

Comment: @Sid Datia, what do you mean answer below? I gave you the answer in my response. In fact your question was about labels (not text fields) so I even guessed that you didn't ask a proper question. Since you didn't post code I gave a couple of suggestions.  One of them worked.

Comment: Oops, my subject header is incorrect, sorry about that. The problem is with JTextFields. I wanted to post code etc in the comment, but that doesnt work. So I posted an answer with the code that I wrote. That answer is below your answer. I hope you can review what I did and comment on it.

Comment: I still don't see an accepted answer anywhere. All your code does is implement my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

createVerticalGlue() does nothing O_O. Maybe I did it wrong.

Overriding maximum size works wonderfully. Why doesnt Java do it by default ???

```
public class TextFTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();

        class X extends JTextField {

            public X(String text) {
                super(text);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                return new Dimension(super.getMaximumSize().width,
                                    getPreferredSize().height);
            }

        }

        jf.getContentPane().setLayout(
                new BoxLayout(jf.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        X f = new X("Hello");
        jf.getContentPane().add(f);

        JTextField f1 = new JTextField("Hello1");
        jf.getContentPane().add(f1);

        jf.getContentPane().add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

        jf.validate();

        jf.setSize(300, 300);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Please excuse my horrible coding standards.